# Which for loop format to use?

Tags: c#, .net

When I am writing code, I sometimes wonder which format is faster;

The old fashioned use of an incrementing variable: i

or

A foreach loop?

Comment: And when writing your code, have you ever tried to test it yourself?

Comment: Duplicate

http://stackoverflow.com/q/365615/1284902

http://stackoverflow.com/q/4661138/1284902

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither is "faster" you need to use the right tool for the job, sometimes `for` is faster sometimes `foreach` is faster.

"micro optimizations" like you are taking about are so insignificant that you will NEVER recover the time in speed up than you will compared to the amount of extra time you took implementing it.

**If your program is slow [use a profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers) on it and find where the real problem is.**

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following links, which might give you more idea about for and foeach.

for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx

foreach: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx

**for vs foreach**

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4ede2e82-e3df-44dc-a863-a871925c5cc5/foreach-or-for-loop-to-improve-performance-c-code
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx