# Any better approaches to doing this in C# 4.0?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, foreach

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows ) 
        avlCols.Add(row.ItemArray[0].ToString().Trim());
```

Comment: What's wrong with this snippet? Looks good to me.

Comment: What is 'better'?! This looks fine to me. Though I would never use foreach loop's in C# as they are less efficient than regular for-loop's  ;)

Comment: does `dt.Rows.ForEach(r => avlCols.Add(r.ItemArray[0].ToString().Trim()));` count?

Comment: @Magnus What don't you think? Just google it: foreach uses more resources/time than for!

Comment: @Vincent: readability and maintainability? 1 Dev's time far outweighs the CPU cycles.

Comment: @p.cambell A for loop isn't really less readable than a foreach loop imho

Comment: Compromise: use `foreach` for readability unless `for` is measurably faster.  It rarely matters but when it matters it matters.

Comment: @Vincent Like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124753/for-vs-foreach-loop-in-c ?  I guess you never use linq than either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

- use good variable names
- use the column name instead of the index
- use LINQ

An example:

```
var names = from personRow in personTable.AsEnumerable()
            select personRow["name"].ToString().Trim();
```

Comment: If you happen to know the index (perhaps you only have one column) it's faster to use the index instead of forcing the DataRow to look up the index from the name once per row.

Comment: Yes it is faster. But until it's a proven _bottleneck_, I'd favor readability and maintainability. And I don't think it would be a bottleneck in a system that (probably) also employs a database.

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing wrong with that code.

If you're looking for a LINQ one-liner to solve the problem, you could try:

```
// I added ToList since it looks like your original used a list.
// If you only need IEnumerable, then you can leave off that call.
var avlCols = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(r => r.Field<string>(0).Trim()).ToList();
```

Or (if you simply need to add those items to an existing list):

```
avlCols.AddRange(dt.AsEnumerable()
                   .Select(r => r.Field<string>(0).Trim()));
```

For both of those options, you have to make sure you add a reference to the System.Data.DataSetExtensions assembly as well as have access to the System.Linq namespace.

Comment: but since OP has `Add()`, the original list could already have some items in it.

Comment: Bala, that's what List.AddRange() is for.

Comment: @Geek - Make sure you have included the System.Linq namespace in your project.

Comment: @Geek is right, .Rows doesn't implement IEnumerable<T> (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855/linq-query-on-a-datatable).  You'll have to use `dt.AsEnumerable()`.

Comment: If you're using System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll to get the Table.AsEnumerable() extension method, I would also use the DataRow.Field() method: `r.Field<string>(0).Trim()`

Comment: @Joel - Good call. I've actually never used DataSetExtensions before...learn something new every day.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get away with:

```
var avlCols = from row in dt.Rows select row.ItemArray[0].ToString().Trim();
```