# Major difference between 'for each' and 'for' loop in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [For vs Foreach loop in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124753/for-vs-foreach-loop-in-c-sharp)

What is the major difference between 'for each' and 'for' loops in [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework)? Is there any performance gain while comparing these two? Which one gives a better performance/faster/memory management?

Comment: I think there's some good reading on this already available....I recently had the same questions myself. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124753/for-vs-foreach-loop-in-c-sharp http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/04/29/123105.aspx http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/01/29/for-vs-foreach-on-arrays-and-lists.aspx The conclusion that I came up with is that it really depends on what you're using them for.

Comment: I am sorry I searched a lot using difference between For and For Each, but the results are based on Ruby,Java etc. I didn't find it for .net :(

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accpeted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [The Code Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Code_Project) article [foreach vs. for (C#)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/foreach.aspx)*.

`foreach` is thinking about everything as a collection and is treating them as a collection. That will also reduce the performance of the work.

To write high performance code that is not for collections, use a `for` loop.

Even for collections, `foreach` may look handy when using, but it's not that efficient. Therefore, I strongly recommend everyone to use a `for` loop rather than `foreach` at any stage.

Comment: Is there any benchmark for the loop thing available? i am to busy to do it my self right now

Comment: @Grrbrr404  - Just read out that article and the other answer on stack overflow you will get idea what to use that what i can suggest you