# Why do C# Arrays use a reference type for Enumeration, but List<T> uses a mutable struct?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, mutable, enumerator

From what I've read, a design decision was made for certain Collections's Enumerator Types to be mutable structs instead of reference types for performance reasons. List.Enumerator is the most well known.

I was investigating some old code that used arrays, and was surprised to discover that C# Arrays return the type SZGenericArrayEnumerator as their generic enumerator type, which is a reference type.

I am wondering if anyone knows why Array's generic iterator was implemented as a reference type when so many other performance critical collections used mutable structs instead.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> From what I've read, a design decision was made for certain Collections's Enumerator Types to be mutable structs instead of reference types for performance reasons.

Good question.

First off, you are correct. Though in general, mutable value types are a bad code smell, in this case they are justified:

- The mutation is almost entirely concealed from the user.
- It is highly unlikely that anyone is going to use the enumerator in a confusing manner.
- The use of a mutable value type actually does solve a realistic performance problem in an extremely common scenario.

> I am wondering if anyone knows why Array's generic iterator was implemented as a reference type when so many other performance critical collections used mutable structs instead.

Because if you're the sort of person who is concerned about the performance of enumerating an array then **why are you using an enumerator in the first place?** It's an **array** for heaven's sake; just write a `for` loop that iterates over its indicies like a normal person and *never* allocate the enumerator. (Or a `foreach` loop; the C# compiler will rewrite the `foreach` loop into the equivalent `for` loop if it knows that the loop collection is an array.)

The only reason why you'd obtain an enumerator from an array in the first place is if you are passing it to a method that takes an `IEnumerator<T>`, in which case *if the enumerator is a struct then you're going to be boxing it anyway*.  Why take on the expense of making the value type and then boxing it?  Just make it a reference type to begin with.

Comment: Given the prevalence (and expressive power) of LINQ, enumerators are likely being retrieved for arrays quite often. For instance, the reflection classes in .NET return arrays for many properties/methods - and using LINQ w/ reflection is quite handy. To my knowledge, most LINQ operators do not perform special case checks to determine if the IEnumerable<> they are dealing with is actually an array.

Comment: @LBushkin: Correct. If you are unwilling to take on the cost of heap allocating and then garbage collecting an *enumerator* then you are also presumably unwilling to take on the cost of heap allocating and garbage collecting *the query*, and all of the enumerator objects it creates, and all the delegates you have to create. Not to mention all the overhead of calling that query (checking arguments for being correct, and so on). LINQ to objects is reasonably performant but it was certainly not designed to minimize heap allocations! LINQ allocates heap memory all over the place.

Comment: Another factor, I suspect, is that the enumerator for the original `List` was designed in the days before generics.  The struct-ness of `List.Enumerator` only affects three types of code: code which explicitly uses type `List.Enumerator`, code which accepts a generic parameter constrained to `IEnumerable`, or code which uses `var` to declare a variable which will hold a list's enumerator.  If a programmer is going to specify `List.Enumerator`, the programmer should know what he's doing.  As for the other two types of code, they couldn't exist when `List.Enumerator` was designed.

Comment: Although `List<T>.Enumerator` was clearly developed after the invention of generics, the Principle of Least Astonishment would favor its working in the same way as `List.Enumerator`, even if the development of generics would mean that some corner-case behaviors might sometimes seem stranger than they otherwise might.

Comment: @supercat: You are correct, and more generally, the whole business of `foreach` being pattern based rather than calling `IEnumerable` methods only was primarily to avoid the boxing penalty in pre-generics strongly typed collections. In the counterfactual world where we started in v1 with generics, there is far less impetus to invent value-typed iterators.

Comment: @EricLippert: Even with generics, using a value-typed iterator would avoid the creation of a heap object every time the 'foreach' loop is entered.  In some ways, though, it might have been nicer if the compiler could look for the existence of a `foreach_GetEnumerator` method; a public `GetEnumerator` method could return an enumerator class, while `foreach_GetEnumerator` returned a struct.  That would seem to give the best of both worlds.

Comment: @EricLippert: "Or a foreach loop; the C# compiler will rewrite the foreach loop into the equivalent for loop if it knows that the loop collection is an array", I never knew that!? Is that documented anywhere (not that I don't believe it), I would be interested to read about it

Comment: For anyone else reading this, this answer covers the optimisations the compiler does http://stackoverflow.com/a/1124763/4500 (Decided not to be lazy and try and search for it myself ;-)

Comment: @supercat, what is this non-generic `List.Enumerator` you mention?  Do you mean `ArrayList.ArrayListEnumerator`?  If so, that's a class, not a struct.

Comment: @phoog: Mea culpa.  If `ArrayListEnumerator` was a class, that makes the decision to have `List<T>.Enumerator` be a struct a little more interesting.  I thought there was some class that used an enumerator struct prior to generics, but maybe not.  In any case, it's only in very rare corner cases that the struct-ness of `List<T>.Enumerator` causes any problem; in a very common case, it is advantageous.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays get some special treatment in the C# compiler. When you use `foreach` on them, the compiler translates it into a `for` loop. So there is no performance benefit in using `struct` enumerators.

`List<T>` on the other hand is a plain class without any special treatment, so using a struct results in better performance.

Comment: isn't all foreach compiled into for loops?

Comment: @OskarKjellin no, normal `foreach` loops become something like `while(enumerator.MoveNext()){var element=enumerator.Current;...}` whereas `foreach` loops over arrays index into the array(`for(int i=0;i<arr.Length;i++)`.

Comment: @OskarKjellin: All `foreach` and `for` loops are *ultimately* compiled into `while` loops. CodeInChaos's point is that `foreach` loops on arrays are actually first compiled into the traditional `for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)` style loop, not the `while(enumtor.MoveNext())` style loop that most `foreach` loops are compiled into.

Comment: @EricLippert Now that you say it's quite obvious given the IEnumerator interface and it's methods. Wasn't really thinking :(