# C# - For vs Foreach - Huge performance difference

Tags: c#, performance, for-loop, foreach

i was making some optimizations to an algorithm that finds the smallest number that is bigger than X, in a given array, but then a i stumbled on a strange difference. On the code bellow, the "ForeachUpper" ends in 625ms, and the "ForUpper" ends in, i believe, a few hours (insanely slower). Why so?

```
  class Teste
{
    public double Valor { get; set; }

    public Teste(double d)
    {
        Valor = d;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Teste: " + Valor;
    }
}

  private static IEnumerable<Teste> GetTeste(double total)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= total; i++)
        {
            yield return new Teste(i);
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int total = 1000 * 1000*30 ;
        double test = total/2+.7;

        var ieTeste = GetTeste(total).ToList();


        Console.WriteLine("------------");

        ForeachUpper(ieTeste.Select(d=>d.Valor), test);
        Console.WriteLine("------------");
        ForUpper(ieTeste.Select(d => d.Valor), test);
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void ForUpper(IEnumerable<double> bigList, double find)
    {
        var start1 = DateTime.Now;

        double uppper = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < bigList.Count(); i++)
        {
            var toMatch = bigList.ElementAt(i);
            if (toMatch >= find)
            {
                uppper = toMatch;
                break;
            }
        }

        var end1 = (DateTime.Now - start1).TotalMilliseconds;

        Console.WriteLine(end1 + " = " + uppper);
    }

    private static void ForeachUpper(IEnumerable<double> bigList, double find)
    {
        var start1 = DateTime.Now;

        double upper = 0;
        foreach (var toMatch in bigList)
        {
            if (toMatch >= find)
            {
                upper = toMatch;
                break;
            }
        }

        var end1 = (DateTime.Now - start1).TotalMilliseconds;

        Console.WriteLine(end1 + " = " + upper);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: I believe this is a possible duplicate 

Click here to see [Duplicate][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44220/difference-between-foreach-and-for-loops-over-an-ienumerable-class-in-c-sharp

Comment: BTW, use the `Stopwatch` class.

Comment: why do you `break` from the `if` ?

Comment: `i was making some optimizations to an algorithm that finds the smallest number that is bigger than X` - You don't need any algorithm for that. You just need `var number = MyList.Where(l => l > x).Max()`. Use LinQ and forget `for` and `foreach` forever.

Comment: @HighCore My LINQ of choice would have been `MyList.OrderBy(l => l).First(l => l > x)`

Comment: @HighCore You have that backwards, it would need to be: `collection.Where(value => value > someConstant).Min();`

Comment: @HighCore: And that's why we get questions that want to do everything in LINQ, even though a foreach would be better. *Don't* forget for and foreach. Just learn when to use each of the tools you are provided with.

Comment: @Alex That is `O(n*log(n))` rather than `O(n)`.  You don't need to sort the whole thing to just get the min/max value.  Oh, and if you do the filtering first you make all operations that follow quicker, rather than doing the filtering at the very end.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth You're right. Im a little exaggerated sometimes.

Comment: You Can Decalare a int Variable For  bigList.Count() in  "ForUpper" Method , To Get it Once.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`IEnumerable<T>` is not indexable.

The `Count()` and `ElementAt()` extension methods that you call in every iteration of your `for` loop are O(n); they need to loop through the collection to find the count or the nth element.

**Moral**: Know thy collection types.

Comment: Regardign `Count()` worth noting that it depends on an actual collection type, if it implements ICollection with Count property `Count()` will use it

Comment: @sll: That's true for `ElementAt`, too. The big differences will go away if the OP would add a `.ToArray()` after the `Select`.

Comment: Funny thing is that this means that an algorithm like quicksort/binarysearch can easily be outmatched by a simple foreach, when the source collection is an enumerable.

Comment: @WoF_Angel: To state that more correctly, you should not use `for` with arbitrary `IEnumerable<T>`s.

Comment: @WOF_Angel: it's the other way around actually: algorithms like quicksort and binary search depend on the collection to be indexable in order to provide their promosed time complexity. Using an enumerable will never make such an algorithm go faster (well, actually any iteration over a collection will pretty much always be faster using a plain array/for loop).

Answer (score 14):

The reason for this difference is that your `for` loop will execute `bigList.Count()` at every iteration. This is really costly in your case, because it will execute the `Select` and iterate the complete result set.

Furthermore, you are using `ElementAt` which again executes the select and iterates it up to the index you provided.