# SendKeys to multiple of the same process

Tags: c#, process, console, console-application, sendkeys

I want my program to be able to use "SendKeys.SendWait()", to send keys to multiple of the same process at once. For example if I had x amount of notepad process open, I want it to be able to count the amount then send keys to all of the processes one by one. The program is a console application written in C#.

The code that I have so far:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
                Process game1 = processes[0];
                do
                {
                    while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
                    {
                            IntPtr p = game1.MainWindowHandle;
                            SetForegroundWindow(p);
                            SendKeys.SendWait("{ESC}");
                            Thread.Sleep(1000);
                            SendKeys.SendWait("^{C}");
                            SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                            SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                            Thread.Sleep(100);
                            SendKeys.SendWait("{A}");                                   
                    }
                } while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.NumPad1);
```

So far the application is able to find the notepad and send the keys but it only sends it to ONE process over and over (the same process). I have tried creating a for loop but I'm not sure how I would count or implement the for loop so I am able to send it to each of the x amount of notepads open.

In the code below, I am able to make it so that it sends between 2 notepad processes, but only because I have told it there are 2 and opened 2.

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
            Process game1 = processes[0];
            do
            {
                while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
                {
                        game1 = processes[0];
                        IntPtr p = game1.MainWindowHandle;
                        SetForegroundWindow(p);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{ESC}");
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("^{C}");
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{A}");

                        game1 = processes[1];
                        p = game1.MainWindowHandle;
                        SetForegroundWindow(p);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{ESC}");
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("^{C}");
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                        SendKeys.SendWait("{A}");
                }
            } while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.NumPad1);
```

Comment: While i do not have the rest of you code to test it, should work if you just change your while loop with a for loop                                                         for (int i = 0; i < processes.Length; i++)
            {
                Process game1 = processes[i];
            }

Comment: @Proxy I have tried to use a foreach loop for processes[0] but i cannot have an int there because it is a process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While i do not have the rest of you code to test it, should work if you just change your while loop with a for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < processes.Length; i++)
        {
            Process game1 = processes[i];
        }
```

Sorry i cannot edit the code in the comment but basically you need just to loop through your process array starting from the first element at the position 0 and increment the counter after you have notified 1 running process

If you want to use the foreach loop you need to do it this way

```
 foreach (var temp in processes)
            {
                Process game1 = temp; // the assigment is not necessary you can just use the temp variable 
            }
```

Basically with foreach you do not need to specify the index because it will "automatically" check each object that is stored inside the array. More details about for vs foreach 
[Difference between foreach and for loops over an IEnumerable class in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44220/difference-between-foreach-and-for-loops-over-an-ienumerable-class-in-c-sharp)